# query Object from Realm List

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSwzH.png)i'm trying to query object from realm

```
class MessageRealm: Object {
dynamic var fromId = String()
dynamic var messageID = String()
dynamic var textDownloadded = String()
override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "messageID"
  }
}

class UsersRealm: Object {
dynamic var sender = String()    
let msgs = List<MessageRealm>()
override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "sender"
    }
}
```

i have two class one for messages and the other for users, every users have a list of messages and i need to query thats message based on (UserRealm.sender)
[This is the realm DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzQa9.png)

Comment: Please be more specific. What are you actually trying to query and what should be your filter criterion? Are you trying to access all messages associated with a user?

Comment: Thank you for your replay.. every sender has own msgs List which contain(fromId - textDownloadded) , what i need is how to query this msgs.. when use like this var messageIndex: Results<MessageRealm>! ... self.messageIndex = try! Realm().objects(MessageRealm.self) ..... every sender get all msgs if you see the attached pic you will understand  that every sender has own  msgs so i need to get this msgs based on sender .... and sorry for poor english thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue by this way if anyone face the same

```
var messageIndex: Results<MessageRealm>!
let realm = try! Realm()
let mssagesRealm = realm.objects(UsersRealm.self).filter("sender = %@", userTitleName)

   for sub in mssagesRealm {
       messageIndex = sub.msgs.sorted(byKeyPath: "timeStamp")
      }
```